# Spring boot connect to MongoDB replica set of mongo container running

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, docker

I have set 2 mongo container which having 27017:27017 and 27018:27017 as port. mongo1 is set as primary while mongo2 set as secondary and used replica set.

mongo1 as primary has both write, read access and mongo2 has only read access

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://abc.xyz:27017/user_demo   
//monog1, abc.xyz is the hostname

spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://abc.xyz:27018/user_demo   
//mongo2
```

If I connect only monogo1 in my normal spring boot program, it works(read, write) and if I set mongo2 it works(only read), but when I set both in one line it gives error

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://abc.xyz:27017,abc.xyz:27018/user_demo?replicaSet=idea-mongo-set
```

I checked replica set is working by storing in mongo1, in mongo2 I can read

So, what is wrong with the last line. Is there any other way to store uri for replica set

In official [spring site](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-nosql.html) it is given

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:secret@mongo1.example.com:12345,mongo2.example.com:23456/test
```

Error I am getting is this

```
2019-01-08 15:56:35.245  INFO 29804 --- [           main] c.j.bootifulmongodb.BootMongoDBApp       : Started BootMongoDBApp in 3.603 seconds (JVM running for 4.373)
2019-01-08 15:56:54.466  INFO 29804 --- [azure.com:27018] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server abc.xyz:27018
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
        at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.4.3.jar:na]
        ... 3 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Please also add the error you get, `it gives an error` is too generic

Comment: Why do you have two question marks before the replica set?

Comment: I see. Yesterday I was trying. Today I tried without mentioning replica set and added after that, may be then teo '?'I added wrongly

Comment: I forgot to add Sven. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your uri is on the right track for connecting to a replica set.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri = mongodb://abc.xyz:27017,abc.xyz:27018/user_demo?replicaSet=idea-mongo-set
```

Is it just a typo that credentials (user, password) are omitted here?

This exact syntax is what we use for our replica set connection uri:

```
mongodb://user:pwd@server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017/our_collection?replicaSet=replica_set_name&authSource=authagainstthiscollection&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-1
```

Comment: I am not using any user. i am usingthe default one like you did for server2. Is not it option the user name and password(if user not created).Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: You able to get any idea John why my uri is not working?

Comment: No because your uri syntax is correct. It is timing out when it tries to connect to one of the replicas apparently.

Comment: But individually I can use both. The second replica is only read mode. I think I know why this problem is occurring. In my application startup, I am loading data to DB. But, the second one has only read permission. Maybe that's why it can not able to read. But, isn't it the first URL will run, if not working the second will run?

Answer (score 2):

Because you set `abc.xyz:27018` hostname in mongo `rs.initiate`, so client will try to access this hostname directly. But this hostname is unreachable for client, it's just a FQDN in your azure cluster.

I think this document will help you [clients use the hostnames listed in the replica set config not the seed list](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/server-discovery-and-monitoring/server-discovery-and-monitoring.rst#clients-use-the-hostnames-listed-in-the-replica-set-config-not-the-seed-list)

Comment: looks like it can help. Can you remove this URL in your answer & give abc.xyz:27018